# Are two different drivers used while using JDBC-ODBC bridge?

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

Prior to Java 8 when there was support for type 1 JDBC drivers, were two different drivers used?

1. The JDBC-ODBC bridge driver included with Java.
2. ODBC driver for Database System being used, which users need to download and install separately and then configure.

Comment: Seems moot.  The bridge driver is no longer shipped with any JVM.  JDK 8 has already passed the end of its support life.

Comment: See announcement in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html

Comment: @duffymo Java 8 is not yet end of life, the current end of public updates date is January 2019 for commercial users (without paying Oracle) and December 2020 for personal users, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The Java app sent queries to the JDBC-ODBC Bridge, which passed them along to the database's ODBC driver, which in turn passed them on to the database itself. The responses followed the same path in the opposite direction.

Comment: Does Database's ODBC driver need to be installed seperately, or does it automatically get installed while installing Database?

Comment: The ODBC driver is usually a separate install.